# Run if statement block if either one of the conditionals are true

Tags: c#

I need to write an if statement block that will run if the value entered is less than $5.65 or greater than 50. How can I do this?

```
using System;
using static System.Console;
namespace HomeWork1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WriteLine ("What is your hourly pay rate");
            double rate;
            string input;
           
            input = ReadLine();
            rate =Convert.ToDouble(input);

            WriteLine("Your hourly pay rate {0}", rate);

            if (rate < 5.65 )
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error entering your pay rate");
          
                    }
            }

            

            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: how can i use the if statement to check if one number is is less than $5.65 or greater than 50

Answer (score 1):

Use the or operator `||` to make this work. The or operator `||` will execute the if block if either one of the conditions are true.

```cs
if (rate < 5.65 || rate > 50)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error entering your pay rate");
}
```